# How to add a new button in layout of the android programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a layout where I have 3 folders and an add button.
What I want is as soon as the user clicks on the add button. A new folder is added to the layout on the position of add button and add button shifts down below the folder-3.
Any suggestions how can I create this dynamic layout. At present I don't have even a single hackish idea by which I can implement this.

[image]

Any help is highly appreciated. 
Thank you.

Comment: You need to use custom layout extending ViewGroup got it?

Comment: Place your folder container layout in the separate than the Add button container layout.use relative layout to place always below  folder container layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [`GridView`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html) with a custom adapter.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center" />
```

You will need a custom adapter to inflate the grid view.
Keep a counter, say `nbFolders` that represent the number of folders.

```
int nbFolders = 0;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(new FolderAdapter());

    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {
            if(position == nbFolders){
                nbFolders++;
                ((FolderAdapter)gridView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    });
}

//Here is where the magic happens
public class FolderAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    public int getCount() {
        return nbFolders + 1;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView yourView;
        if (convertView == null) {
           yourView = new TextView(YourActivity.this);
        } else {
            yourView = (TextView) convertView;
        }

        if(position < nbFolders){
            yourView.setText("Folder " + (position + 1));
        }else{
            yourView.setText("Add");
        }

        return yourView;
    }

}
```

Comment: It works like a charm, but out of curiosity when I change the textview to a button the button doesn't show the same property as the textview is showing. Any insights ?

Comment: @BhanuPratapSingh because it is not a textview, it is a button and thus should look like one.

Comment: I think you got it wrong. When changed the textview to button, it is not working. You click on the Add button and nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Create button with `button = new Button(getApplicationContext())`, than get your viewGroup object (i guess LinearLayout) with `layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById (R.id.<yourLayoutId>)` and then just `layout.addView(button)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
//the layout on which you are working
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_tags);

//set the properties for button
Button btnTag = new Button(this);
btnTag.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
btnTag.setText("Button");
btnTag.setId(some_random_id);

//add button to the layout
layout.addView(btnTag);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(context);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
Button btn = new Button(this); 
btn .setLayoutParams(params);
layout.addView(btn);
```